# Is there a bibliography style that just prints the BibTeX entries cited?

Tags: biblatex

One thing I dislike about bibliography styles is that sometimes information is lost and some citation styles make it difficult to link the citation and the entry in the bibliography. An extreme reaction would be to print the `.bib` file used in place of the bibliography, not run `biber` or `bibtex` and leave the unformatted entries in `\textcite` and friends.

Is a slightly nicer version achievable in BibLaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
    title={foo},
    year={2011},
    journal={bla}
}

@article{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
    title={bar},
    year={2010},
    journal={bla}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some words \textcites{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St}{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> Some words **Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St** and **Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec**.
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> @article{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St,
>
> ```
>     Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
>
>     title={foo},
>     year={2011},
>     journal={bla}
> }
>
> @article{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec,
>     Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
>     title={bar},
>     year={2010},
>     journal={bla}
> ```

or perhaps

> **Bibliography**
>
> **Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St**:
>
> author: K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack
>
> title: foo
>
> year: 2011
>
> journal: bla
>
> **Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec**
>
> author: K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack
>
> title: bar
>
> year: 2010

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you want? If you get bold '**Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St**' in your document, you did not run Biber on your document and the citations do not look as expected. You also forgot `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` in your MWE. [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Sorry, I understand how to run `biber` normally for a document. What I'm after is an esoteric bibliography style that instead of *styling* the entries simply prints the BibTeX entries verbatim. The citestyle may be different, but the way they're printed when `biber` is not run is actually satisfactory I think.

Comment: If I add the missing `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` in your example and compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX I obtain https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHzJQ.png Which looks informative enough.

Comment: LaTeX's defaults are very good, and I'm being picky, but for example the names are collapsed in `et al.` and the forename is suppressed. I know I can use options to `biblatex` like `maxcitenames`to fix each of those things, but distinguishing between the `notes` field and the `address` field is harder.

Comment: On reflection, the MWE may be more distracting than helpful in this case.

Comment: The only time that "sometimes information is lost" from a given entry is if the entry contains fields that aren't appropriate for a given entry type. E.g., if an entry of type `@book` contains a field named `journal`, then both biblatex and bibtex will -- correctly! -- ignore the field, and its contents will end up being "lost". But I'd say that this is exactly as it should be: the mere fact that some fields are getting lost might be a clue that there are errors that must be fixed. The real remedy is to change either the entry type (to `@article`?) or the field name (to `booktitle`, maybe).

Comment: That's a good point, Mico and I would definitely still take note and respect `biber -V`. But if I made mistakes, the burden of those mistakes still fall on the reader, instead of the author. At least in the `style=debug`, the reader is given a chance to recover information if the author makes a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mico makes some very good points when he questions the motivation behind this approach.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416262/is-there-a-bibliography-style-that-just-prints-the-bibtex-entries-cited/416268#comment1040502_416262)

As you can see the output is rather overwhelming and a reader might simply get lost in the wall of information you inflict upon her.
A well chosen bibliography style will make it much easier for your readers to find what they are looking for.
Even dropping the entire `.bib` file on your reader can not guarantee that you have not made mistakes that might cause confusion or hinder your readers to find the correct citations. The only situation in which the `.bib` file gives your reader an advantage over the output in the bibliography as produced by a proper style arises when your `.bib` entries don't conform to `biblatex`'s data model, but you are easily warned of that with `biber --validate-datamodel`. All in all, the disadvantages of simply showing the entire `.bib` file should outweigh the advantages: I certainly have never seen anyone attempt to pass their `.bib` file off as a proper bibliography in a paper or textbook.

---

That said, you can use the `debug` style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=debug]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This style only lists fields that are known to `biblatex` and Biber in the data model. If you use weird fields or have a typo in the field name, they are gone. Of course `biber --validate-datamodel` warns you about this.

---

Just for fun, here is a solution that comes closer to what you originally intended.

Run LaTeX with shell escape enabled twice on the following. There is o need for further Biber runs, the required runs are already done via the shell escape. If you decide to additionally run Biber normally, the citations will turn from bold to their normal form in `style=debug` as shown above. If you decide not to run Biber as normal, you will of course be met with warnings that remind you to run Biber again, but you can ignore these warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=debug]{biblatex}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines=true}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{onlycitedsort.conf}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <output_safechars>1</output_safechars>
  <sorting>
    <sort order="1">
      <sortitem order="1">entrykey</sortitem>
    </sort>
  </sorting>
</config>
\end{filecontents*}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.bcf}
  {\immediate\write18{biber --output_format=bibtex \jobname.bcf}%
   \immediate\write18{biber --tool --configfile=onlycitedsort.conf \jobname_biber.bib}}
 {\typeout{Please rerun LaTeX.}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero,vizedom:related}
\IfFileExists{\jobname_biber_bibertool.bib}
  {\lstinputlisting{\jobname_biber_bibertool.bib}}
  {empty bibliography}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]